# box2d 2.2 version replacment for b2PolygonShape SetAsOrientedBox

Tags: box2d

what is the replacement for b2PolygonShape SetAsOrientedBox 
for the new box2d version.

for example what will be the right code for this example ( in action script)

```
var leftAxleContainerShape:b2PolygonShape = new b2PolygonShape();
            leftAxleContainerShape.SetAsOrientedBox(axleContainerWidth/worldScale,axleContainerHeight/worldScale,new b2Vec2(-axleContainerDistance/worldScale,axleContainerDepth/worldScale),axleAngle*degreesToRadians);
            var leftAxleContainerFixture:b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
            leftAxleContainerFixture.density=3;
            leftAxleContainerFixture.friction=3;
            leftAxleContainerFixture.restitution=0.3;
            leftAxleContainerFixture.filter.groupIndex=-1;
            leftAxleContainerFixture.shape=leftAxleContainerShape;
```

Comment: What port is this, Flash? I expect you could implement it without too much difficulty by copying the old source. I don't know where the old Flash source is but if it helps, the C++ version is here: https://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp#44

Comment: Just had a quick check in the Flash 10 download here: http://www.box2dflash.org/download The old function is there to copy.

Comment: the truth im using the c++ box2d , the flash is just something i try to port to c++

Comment: In that case, you can use SetAsBox which is an overloaded function in the C++ version. You just need to pass the extra parameters when you call the function.

Comment: yes this is what i did , thanks iforce2d you have great site!